# Create and instantiate python 2d dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

I have two python dictionaries:

```
ccyAr = {'AUDCAD','AUDCHF','AUDJPY','AUDNZD','AUDUSD','CADCHF','CADJPY','CHFJPY','EURAUD','EURCAD','EURCHF','EURGBP','EURJPY','EURNZD','EURUSD','GBPAUD','GBPCAD','GBPCHF','GBPJPY','GBPNZD','GBPUSD','NZDCAD','NZDCHF','NZDJPY','NZDUSD','USDCAD','USDCHF','USDJPY'}

data  = {'BTrades', 'BPips', 'BProfit', 'STrades', 'SPips', 'SProfit', 'Trades', 'Pips', 'Profit', 'Won', 'WonPC', 'Lost', 'LostPC'}
```

I've been trying to get my head round how to most elegantly create a construct in which each of 'data' exists in each of 'ccyAr'.  The following are the two I feel are the closest, but the first results (now I realise) in arrays and the latter i more like pseudocode:

1.

```
table={ { data:[] for d in data } for ccy in ccyAr }
```

2.

```
for ccy in ccyAr:
    for d in data:
        table['ccy']['d'] = 0
```

I also want to set each of the entries to int 0 and I'd like to do it in one go.  I'm struggling with the comprehension method as I end up creating each value of each inside directory member as a list instead of a value 0.

I've seen the autovivification piece but I don't want to mimic perl, I want to do it the pythonic way.  Any help = cheers.

Comment: I'm happy to change my question so that it refers to sets if it pleases the moderators (I don't want to fu replies below).  I thought these were dictionaries as they essentially appeared to me to be associative arrays of keys without values (yet).  Maybe I need to R more of TFM.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
for ccy in ccyAr:
    for d in data:
        table['ccy']['d'] = 0
```

Is close.

```
table = {}
for ccy in ccyAr:
    table[ccy] = {}
    for d in data:
        table[ccy][d] = 0
```

Also, ccyAr and data in your question are sets, not dictionaries.

Comment: This gets the nod for me not needing to import anything. Chrs.

Comment: IMO, you should still look at the [pandas package](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/) since it is its exact purpose to have 2d dictionaries...

Answer (score 1):

What you are searching for is a [pandas DataFrame](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.html#pandas.DataFrame) of shape `data` x `ccyAr`. I give a minimal example here:

```
import pandas as pd

data = {'1', '2'}
ccyAr = {'a','b','c'}

df = pd.DataFrame(np.zeros((len(data), len(ccyAr))))
```

Then the most important step is to set both the columns and the index. If your two so-called dictionaries are in fact sets (as it seems in your code), use:

```
df.columns = ccyAr
df.index = data
```

If they are indeed dictionaries, you instead have to call their keys method:

```
df.columns = ccyAr.keys()
df.index = data.keys()
```

You can `print df` to see that this is actually what you wanted:

```
  | a | c | b
-------------
1 | 0   0   0
2 | 0   0   0
```

And now if you try to access via `df['a'][1]` it returns you 0. It is the best solution to your problem.

Answer (score 0):

How to do this using a dictionary comprehension:

```
table = {ccy:{d:0 for d in data} for ccy in ccyAr}
```

Comment: Does the notion of the absence of values make each member =0? This was what I was looking for, of course {} instead of [] was the difference , at least I think. I will have to run it the check.

Comment: That was my mistake. I don't know why I thought you wanted an empty dict. That can be changed to 0.